# Network Analysis Shortest path with original line segments as output

Tags: qgis, python, algorithm, shortest-path, network-analysis

I've managed to batch run the shortest path algorithm and the shortest route (point to layer) in the output is perfect, except that I really need the individual attribute tables of the line segments in the output. Any idea if there is a way to produce something like this?

I'm basically looking to create a new version of my line input layer with the all original segments/attributes intact, but with the ID of whichever start point (x however many, if the same line feature is used by more than one start/end point combination) was used for that output line feature.

Right now, I’m getting complete line from a location to `z` location, but I need to know which ‘roads’ make up that full path.

- Edit: added screenshots of data.

[image: Result of shortest path algorithm from BQ06088I to NYQN3430]

[image: Network lines as they exist in the input layer]

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot of your data as an example?

Comment: @ValP thank you so much for getting back to me! I just added screenshots to my original post.

Answer (score 0):

Activate your' "roads" layer and use select by expression to select all features within the shortest path.
`within($geometry, geometry(get_feature_by_id('Shortest path',1)))`